# Errors while compiling Emgu CV from source

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, emgucv

I'm trying to compile Emgu CV 2.4.9 from git source. I followed the instructions given in the site.

I cloned `git://git.code.sf.net/p/emgucv/code` this repo, switched to 2.4.9 branch, then I ran `git submodule update --init --recursive`

After that I ran `Build_Binary_x86.bat` to create the visual studio solution. I opened up the solution in Visual Studio 2013, but when I tried to build the project, I'm getting the following errors.

[image]

I haven't made any changes in the source code, but still I'm unable to build the project. Is there something I'm doing wrong?